# Pandas : combine rows of a dataframe with a list

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Letters': ['A','B','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 'Numbers': [5,2,3,8,6,4,9]})

     Letters  Numbers
0       A        5
1       B        2
2       C        3
3       D        8
4       E        6
5       F        4
6       G        9
```

and a list

```
combine = [['A', 'C'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
```

I am looking for the following output which combines the list 'combine' to df['Letters'] and sums df['Numbers'] so that it looks like this :

```
     Letters  Numbers
0      A,C       8
1       B        2
2       D        8
3     E,F,G      19
```

I've been trying to figure out a solution using groupby but I don't think that's the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `groupby` will work if you define the groups properly:

```
d = {
    'A': ('A', 'C'),
    'B': ('B'),
    'C': ('A', 'C'),
    'D': ('D'),
    'E': ('E', 'F', 'G'),
    'F': ('E', 'F', 'G'),
    'G': ('E', 'F', 'G'),
}

df['Group'] = df.Letters.apply(lambda x: d[x])
```

Note that you need to use tuples (which are hashable) rather than lists.

```
In [39]: df.groupby('Group').sum()
Out[39]: 
           Numbers
Group             
(A, C)           8
(E, F, G)       19
B                2
D                8
```

You could certainly define the groups more programmatically, but this will work.

---

**Edit**: Anton Protopopov provided a solution to generate `d` programmatically.

```
import itertools as it

d = {}
[d.update({let:tuple(comb)}) for comb in combine for let in df.Letters if let in comb]
[d.update({let:(let)}) for let in df.Letters if let not in it.chain(*combine)]
```

Comment: You could create that dict with (may be not the best way): `d = {};
[d.update({let:comb}) for comb in combine for let in df.Letters if let in comb];
[d.update({let:let}) for let in df.Letters if let not in it.chain(*combine1)]`

Comment: Thanks, good point. Let's see if @mohitos expresses an interest.

Comment: Thank you Gentlemen! The combination of your joint efforts gets me to where I need to be.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov I've included your solution in my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I could suggested solution with cycles, [isin](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwir0t6ElObMAhVIMJoKHXNaDtcQFgggMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.Series.isin.html&usg=AFQjCNHEOa4btqDkFrnduWNtwXrgJ6qM6A&sig2=9mWAHM4THJZJlOu7yn-zGQ&bvm=bv.122129774,d.bGs) and [it.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

l = []
for comb in combine:
    mask = df.Letters.isin(comb)
    l.append([comb, df.Numbers[mask].sum()])

whole_mask = df.Letters.isin(it.chain(*combine))
df_fin = pd.concat([df[~whole_mask], pd.DataFrame(l, columns=df.columns)])


In [40]: df_fin
Out[40]:
     Letters  Numbers
0          B        2
1          D        8
2     [A, C]        8
3  [E, F, G]       19
```

*Note:* But I think @IanS solution with groupby is better.

Comment: @IanS thanks, you could add some code for creating combine `dict`